# How to remember programmatically the security settings for webcam/microphone?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a flex application for online interview. I need to check box of remember every time. My question is how to check remember me checkbox programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing from the same server (domain) you indicate that recall the first time , security policies Flash remember this decision.
Do programmatically is not possible , imagine if this was released how easy it would be to access your peripherals without your permission.

What is the Save option ?
If you select Save , you make the choice to allow or deny access shall apply to all uses of this website, not only to the application that is running. That is, Flash Player will not ask if this website applications can access your camera and microphone.

If you select Save , the selection of permission or denial of access shall be valid only while the application is running . That is, if you run this application or any other application on this website , Flash Player will ask again whether to allow or deny access to the camera and microphone .

regars